# Internet connection gets Disconnected Continuously

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet

I am using a **NETGEAR** router **DG834G** router which is about 6 months old. I continuously get disconnected from the Internet. Resetting the router helps but the Internet gets disconnected again and again.

I am using the DSL connection in which the router and the modem are in the same device. I checked to see if there were any broken connections but there weren't any.

Comment: does it happen when you are connected with a cable? Wifi only? ugh. DG834G does not have wifi........ so are tagging this question as wireless-networking?

Comment: Sounds like a DSL signal problem contact your ISP

Comment: When you say "disconnected from the Internet", do you mean that you can still reach the router?

Answer (score 0):

You evidently either have a defective DSL Modem/Router device, or a defective DSL line. Contact your DSL provider and see if they can verify anything from their end; if they provided the Modem/Router they might be able to provide another one to try - if they made you buy it in the first place, perhaps it's still under warranty if it's only 6 months old, and you can try a new one that way - or do you know anyone else with a DSL line (or a bought but now disused DSL modem)  that you can do a diagnostic swap with, to see if your modem/router works on their line, or theirs works on your line - that would help narrow the problem down to the line or the Modem/Router, and you'd know whether the solution was a new Modem/Router (or Modem and Router) or getting on the case of your DSL service provider to fix the line.

Did it ever work? I'm assuming above that it worked until recently - if not there, might be other issues. Might you have a misplaced DSL line filter (such as someone placing one before the DSL modem)?

Comment: The most likely scenario is that some device connected to his phone line is missing a DSL filter. It's easy to miss an alarm system or satellite TV receiver, and it's easy to move a cordless phone base station or wired phone and forget to move the DSL filter with it.